# Equivalent of adding strings to a loop, for strings (matlab)?

Tags: string, matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix

How would I be able to do the equivalent of this with strings:

```
a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
c = [];
for i=1:5
b = a(1,:)+i;
c = [c;b];   
end

c =

 2     3     4
 3     4     5
 4     5     6
 5     6     7
 6     7     8
```

Basically looking to combine several strings into a Matrix.

Comment: A general comment: loops like the one you describe above are very inefficient, since `c` is growing with each iteration. Better to preallocate `c` by replacing `c = []` with `c = zeros(5, 3)`, and then adjust the line `c = [c;b];` accordingly. Or better yet, omit the loop entirely using `bsxfun(@plus, (1:5)', a(1, :))`.

Answer (score 3):

You're growing a variable in a loop, which is a kind of sin in Matlab :) So I'm going to show you some better ways of doing array concatenation.

There's cell strings:

```
>> C = {
    'In a cell string, it'
    'doesn''t matter'
    'if the strings'
    'are not of equal lenght'};

>> C{2}
ans = 
    doesn't matter
```

Which you could use in a loop like so:

```
% NOTE: always pre-allocate everything before a loop
C = cell(5,1);

for ii = 1:5
    % assign some random characters
    C{ii} = char( '0'+round(rand(1+round(rand*10),1)*('z'-'0')) );
end
```

There's ordinary arrays, which have as a drawback that you have to know the size of all your strings beforehand:

```
a = [...
    'testy'     % works
    'droop'
];

b = [...
    'testing'              % ERROR: CAT arguments dimensions 
    'if this works too'    % are not consistent. 
    ];
```

for these cases, use `char`:

```
>> b = char(...
      'testing',...
      'if this works too'...
      );
b =
   'testing          '
   'if this works too'
```

Note how `char` pads the first string with spaces to fit the length of the second string. Now again: **don't use this in a loop**, unless you've pre-allocated the array, or if there really is no other way to go.

Type `help strfun` on the Matlab command prompt to get an overview of all string-related functions available in Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

You mean storing a string on each matrix position? You can't do that, since matrices are defined over basic types. You can have a CHAR on each position:

```
>> a = 'bla';
>> b = [a; a]  

b <2x3 char> =

bla
bla

>> b(2,3) = 'e'

b =

bla
ble
```

If you want to store matrices, use a cell array ([MATLAB reference](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cell.html), [Blog of Loren Shure](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/06/21/cell-arrays-and-their-contents/)), which are *kind of* similar but using "{}" instead of "()":

```
>> c = {a; a}

c = 

    'bla'
    'bla'

>> c{2}

ans =

bla
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could your example be used in a FOR loop? E.g. a = 'bla'; for i=7 c(i)=[c;a]; end

Comment: OK, it is very well explained in Rody's answer. Also the clarification about preallocation. A last (unrelated) thing: notice that he avoids using "i" as variable name, because if you do that you are hiding the value of the constant sqrt(-1) --complex numbers--. The same apply to "j"